# how to delete duplicate rows from datagridview with unknown cloumns?

Tags: c#, for-loop, datagridview, duplicates, rows

how to delete duplicate rows from datagridview with unknown cloumns?

this code isnt work.

```
int rws1 = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
           
int cl = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
            
for(int j = 0; j <= rws1; j++)
  {
    for (int l = 0; l <= rws1; l++)
      {
        for (int i = 1; i <= cl; i++)
          {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value == dataGridView1.Rows[l].Cells[i].Value)
              {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[j]);
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by “unknown columns” ? The code appears to get the column count with… `int cl = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;` ? The three (3) `for` loops on the other hand are going to cause some issues and will most likely end up throwing an index out of range exception. The issue is that you CAN NOT “remove” rows from the grid as your code does. Each time your code “removes” a row from the grid, then the grids `Rows.Count` decreases. Eventually, the starting `rws1` variable will be greater than the number of rows and end up throwing an index out of range exception.

Comment: unknown columns means i dont know the number of columns and its add random

Comment: So... `int cl = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;` .... means... _"i dont know the number of columns"_ ... ? ... hmm.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong here.

1. As JohnG stated, deleting items from a list as you iterate through it will throw an [index-out-of-range exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=net-5.0).  Mark them for deletion instead and come back to them after the checks are finished.
2. Even after fixing that: every time `j == l`, you'll mark *every* row as a duplicate of itself. There's also a *lot* of redundant checking in this nested for-loop. We'll restructure the loops to address this to only compare rows that haven't been compared yet.
3. Even after fixing that: when `j==rws1`, `l==rws1`, or `i==cl`, another index-out-of-range exception is thrown. Your loops should only check for `<` instead of `<=`.
4. You are deleting rows as duplicates if *any* of the cells are equal.  But what if the rest of the two rows' cells are not equal? Is it still considered a duplicate row? I'll assume every cell must be equal for this example.  To address this we will reverse-think and assume a row is a duplicate until a non-equal cell is found.

Let's jump in the code:

```
int rows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
int cols = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
var toDelete = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
        
for(int outer = 0; outer < rows; outer++)
{
    // Only check rows not previously marked as duplicates.
    if (!toDelete.Contains(dataGridView1.Rows[outer]))
    {
        /* Start the inner loop at the row following the outer loop,
           because previous rows have already been checked. */
        for (int inner = outer + 1; inner < rows; inner++)
        {
            if (!toDelete.Contains(dataGridView1.Rows[inner]))
            {
                bool duplicate = true;

                // Assume inner row is a duplicate until proven otherwise.
                for (int col = 0; col < cols && duplicate; col++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[outer].Cells[col].Value != dataGridView1.Rows[inner].Cells[col].Value)
                    {
                        duplicate = false;
                    }
                }

                if (duplicate)
                {
                    toDelete.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[inner]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Remove duplicates.
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in toDelete)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
}

// Clean up.
toDelete.Clear();
```